# Draw direction marker at certain points on a polyline - leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How can I draw direction markers like the one I have in the screenshot showing the direction of the polyline only at certain specified points on the leaflet map?.I know there is a [plugin](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator) which draws arrows along the polyline(which is not what I want). What I want is something similar to Google Maps backward arrow symbol.Can someone please help.[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a similar display, where you able to find any solution? Thanks.

Comment: No sorry, we changed it to a triangle shape.